# I would like to switch on the Raspberry GPIO using an NPN transistor (2n2222)

Tags: rpi.gpio

Hello guys I am currently working on a project. and I would like to turn on a GPIO pin when my LED on the circuit below turns on. I'm lost to where I should tie my input GPIO pin. please help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don’t know where you got this but it is unlikely to work

Comment: @Milliways I made it my self. So it is not possible to control a GPIO using a transistor switch?

Comment: I don’t know what you are actually trying to accomplish. Are you trying to use GPIO to turn LED on?

Comment: No. What I am trying to achieve is.. I would like to use the NPN transistor as switch for turning on GPIO Pin

Comment: And what is supposed to turn the LED on?

Comment: @Milliways Nope.. Just to detect the signal coming from transistor

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

How to use a NPN transistor to "*turn on*" a Rpi GPIO pin?

***Answer***

Ah, you cannot "*turn on*" a Rpi GPIO pin. She won't listen to you, but you can ask her to behave as input or output! :)

In geek English:

> 1. A Rpi GPIO pin can be in "input mode" or "output mode".
> 2. An "input" pin can input/read a signal which can be High or Low.
> 3. An "output" pin can output/switch a LED, eg, High to switch on, Low  to switch off, (or vice versa, depending on circuit).

[image: converter]

I have drawn a circuit showing how to convert a loud (5V) signal to a soft (3V3) signal.  The fair lady prefers a soft voice - loud voice can kill her! :)

[image: converter 2]

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

[NPN Transistor Tutorial - Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html)

Comment: used the wrong term.. that what I want to do.. to make GPIO as input..

Comment: I followed your digram above but it seems that I am not getting the expected output.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you use the wrong resistors - not any resistor will do!  Is the left most box working?

Comment: yep it worked fine.. I replace it with another base voltage as trigger.. this is still somehow connected to the pump I ask about in the other question.. What  I did was I used the voltage across the pumps wires run it throug a voltage divider circuit with 3V output and connected it to the transistor base as trigger. what resistor values should I use.

Comment: I am confused.  Perhaps you can update your question with a schematic.